# How to bring together data from two lists in excel when some categories have been combined in one of the lists

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have two excel sheets:

- One lists the population of local council areas in 2011
- The other lists the population of local council areas in 2021

I want to use index match (on their names) to create a single list of the 2021 local councils with a column for population in 2011 and a column for population in 2021.

BUT - some of the local council areas have merged together since 2011, so the lists are not quite compatible.

I have a lookup list showing which old councils merged into which new ones.
How can I easily link them so the new names pick up and sum the values from the relevant old councils.
I think I've seen someone do this by creating an array, or a named range for the lookup table somehow?

Comment: seems relatively straight forward, in the 2011 list add a column with a lookup on your third list to get the 2021 names. Then in the 2021 list do a sumifs on 2011 list for the population using the added 2021 name column.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, that'll do it, I was overcomplicating it, thinking I could do it in a single step, but this is clear and straightforward.

Comment: yes, probably could have been done with one formula, but with some loss of clarity. Also, consider adding appropriate checks to make sure you didn't double/under/mis count etc.  I wouldn't want this thread to become "evidence" of voter fraud, ;-)

Comment: lol. Not voting in this case, just demographics. Will be straightforward to check the totals remain consistent, always worth building in you're right. thanks again

Comment: Could you provide sample tables here?